# Configure AutoMapper to map to concrete types but allow Interfaces in the definition of my class

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have some code that is similar to what is below.  Basically it represents getting data from a web service and converting it into client side objects.

```
void Main()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingFromWebService, Something>();    
    Mapper.CreateMap<HasSomethingFromWebService, HasSomething>(); 
    // Service side
    var hasSomethingFromWeb = new HasSomethingFromWebService();
    hasSomethingFromWeb.Something = new SomethingFromWebService
            { Name = "Whilly B. Goode" };
    // Client Side                
    HasSomething hasSomething=Mapper.Map<HasSomething>(hasSomethingFromWeb);  
}    
// Client side objects
public interface ISomething
{
    string Name {get; set;}
}    
public class Something : ISomething
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}    
public class HasSomething
{
    public ISomething Something {get; set;}
}    
// Server side objects
public class SomethingFromWebService
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}    
public class HasSomethingFromWebService
{
    public SomethingFromWebService Something {get; set;}
}
```

The problem I have is that I want to use Interfaces in my classes (HasSomething.ISomething in this case), but I need to have AutoMapper map to concrete types.  (If I don't map to concrete types then AutoMapper will create proxies for me.  That causes other problems in my app.)

The above code gives me this error:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   SomethingFromWebService -> ISomething
>   UserQuery+SomethingFromWebService -> UserQuery+ISomething

**So my question is, how can I map to a concrete type and still use interfaces in my class?**

***NOTE:*** I tried adding this mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingFromWebService, ISomething>();
```

But then the object returned is not of type `Something` it returns a generated Proxy using ISomething as the template.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So I figured something that seems to work.

If I add these two mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingFromWebService, Something>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingFromWebService, ISomething>().As<Something>();
```

then it works as I want.

I have not been able to find any documentation on the 'As' method (try googling for that! :), but it seems to be a mapping redirection.

For example: For this Mapping (`ISomething`) resolve it `As` a `Something`.

Comment: Thanks for this, this helped me out a lot. Unless I am mistaken though, you only need the second mapping. I think the second mapping must make the first redundant?

Comment: No, you still need the first mapping for the concrete type, otherwise AutoMapper wouldn't know how to map from SomethingFromWebService to Something

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'm struggling for 2 hours now, and it fixes my problem!