# Details about what the As<>() method does in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have done a fair amount of Googling and I have looked through the AutoMapper wiki and I cannot find a definition of what the As<> method does in AutoMapper.

I have some guesses.  I have played with it a bit.  But I feel like I need to see some documentation.

I think that the name of the method is too commonplace a word for effective googling.

If anyone knows where the docs are on this method (or knows the ins-and-outs of it) please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mapping redirection. The following test demonstrates it:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DestinationTypePolymorphismTest
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerStubDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerDTO : CustomerStubDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderDTO
    {
        public CustomerStubDTO Customer { get; set; }
    }


    [Test]
    public void Mapper_Should_Allow_Overriding_Of_Destination_Type()
    {
        var order = new Order() { Customer = new Customer() { Id = 1, Name = "A" } };
        Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerStubDTO>().As<CustomerDTO>();
        var orderDto = Mapper.Map<Order, OrderDTO>(order);

        var customerDto = (CustomerDTO)orderDto.Customer;
        Assert.AreEqual("A", customerDto.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, customerDto.Id);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have not been able to find any documentation on the 'As' method, but near as I can tell, it is a mapping redirection.

For example, this code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomethingFromWebService, ISomething>().As<Something>();
```

Means: For this Mapping (`ISomething`) resolve it `As` a `Something`.

Note: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13075588/16241) can provide a bit of context for this answer.