# automapper, mapping to an interface

Tags: automapper

I am using automapper (for .net 3.5). Here is an example to illustrate what I am trying to do:

I want to map an A object to a B object. Class definitions:

```
class A
{
    public I1 MyI { get; set; }

}
class B
{        
    public I2 MyI { get; set; }
}

interface I1
{
    string StringProp1 { get; }
}
interface I2
{
    string StringProp1 { get; }
}

class CA : I1
{
    public string StringProp1
    {
        get { return "CA String"; }
    }
    public string StringProp2 { get; set; }
}
class CB : I2
{
    public string StringProp1
    {
        get { return "CB String"; }
    }
    public string StringProp2 { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping code:

```
        A a = new A()
        {
            MyI = new CA()
        };
        // Mapper.CreateMap ...?
        B b = Mapper.Map<A,B>(a);
```

I want the resulting object b to be populated with an instance of CB. So automapper needs to know that A maps to B, CA maps to CB, and when creating a B populate it's MyI prop with a CB, how do I specify this mapping?

Comment: Honestly, the use of short variable names make it way less readable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure AutoMapper to map to concrete types but allow Interfaces in the definition of my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075588/configure-automapper-to-map-to-concrete-types-but-allow-interfaces-in-the-defini)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());

        var a = new A()
        {
            MyI = new CA()
            {
                StringProp2 = "sp2"
            }
        };

        var b = Mapper.Map<A, B>(a);

        Console.WriteLine("a.MyI.StringProp1: " + a.MyI.StringProp1);
        Console.WriteLine("b.MyI.StringProp1: " + b.MyI.StringProp1);

    }
}
```

>= AutoMapper 2.0.0

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<CA, CB>();
        CreateMap<CA, I2>().As<CB>();                                                                       
        CreateMap<A, B>();
    }
}
```

AutoMapper 1.1.0.188 (.Net 3.5)

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<CA, CB>();

        CreateMap<CA, I2>()
            .ConstructUsing(Mapper.Map<CA, CB>)
            ;

        CreateMap<A, B>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... unfortunately the automapper version i use doesn't seem to support the As mathod. As mentioned I'm using the 3.5 version. Do you know what the corresponding code for that would look like?

Comment: @tyronecopex which AutoMapper version is that?

Comment: @tyronecopex Found it already. You are probably using 1.1.0.188. See my updated answer.

Comment: RTD link: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Mapping-inheritance.html#as